# Manually get specific localized string

Tags: ios, localization

Let say I already put everything on Localizable.strings for several language. As for now I use `NSLocalizedString` and it return the text based on `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]` setting. Now I need to get specific string for each language.

Let say I want to put it on select language setting and show it when user press Submit button. So it will show a dialog with a message "Select this language?" on respective language that user select.

Answer (score 0):

You can get any translation from any language file by loading it manually:

```
- (NSString *)localizedString:(NSString *)string forCountry:(NSString *)countryCode {
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Localizable" ofType:@"strings" inDirectory:nil forLocalization:countryCode];
NSBundle *dataBundle = [[NSBundle alloc] initWithPath:[bundlePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
return NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(string, @"Localizable", dataBundle, nil); }
```

Does this help?